# Which AVRs are pin-compatible with the ATtiny2313?

Tags: avr

Until the 4kb upgrade to the ATtiny2313 is available, which AVRs can I substitute when the ATtiny2313 is too tiny?

Comment: ATtiny4313, no? Or did you mean that one with the "4kb upgrade to the ATtiny2313"?

Comment: This question is now obsolete. The 4313 is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't one!

Comment: I do not know the atmel series to write an answer, but often there is no replacement excluding the one they are working on. Makes sense why they are working on it now.

Comment: I think you may be right. I've heard that the ATtiny2313 has an unusual pin arrangement for AVRs (I love the very convenient PORTB all on one side) perhaps shared with very obsolete old parts with no RAM...

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify if you need the same pin out because of a software issue or a hardware issue...

If it is purely not being able to solder a chip to a board because of a different pin out and you have to figure something out, you can [dead bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_construction#.27Dead_bug.27_construction) the chip.